# What is the general Traffic Flow of 2 Clients connected to the same AP?

Tags: wireless, network, traffic

If **Client A** and **Client B** are both connected to **Access Point C** and A + B want to talk to each other, does C act as a switch between the two of these clients or does C have to send that traffic back to an Access Switch first to then forward the data back down to the AP?

To try and explain out of the below what would be expected?

Client A <--> Access Point C <--> Client B

**OR**

Client A <--> Access Point C <--> Switch <--> Access Point C <--> Client B

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client A <--> Access Point C <--> Client B

A switch is not necessary.  It might be helpful to think of the AP as a wireless bridge.